# Metal - the scene rendered upside down

Tags: glsl, metal

I am trying to convert this [glsl](http://glslsandbox.com/e#20124.7) into my `Metal` app for learning purposes. It can render successfully. However, There are 2 issues:

1. the scene is upside down.
2. I use mouse to rotate the camera. When I move my mouse, the scene rotate to totally unseen angle.

I believe the 2 issues is related, How can I resolve this issues? Below are my `Metal` code:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

constant const float gtime = 0.0;//<-- stop the animation for now.
constant const float pi = 3.141592653589793;


float sdPlane( float3 p) {
    return p.y + 0.4;
}

float sdSphere( float3 p,  float r) {
    return length(p) - r;
}

float sdCapsule( float3 p, float3 a, float3 b, float r ) {
    float3 pa = p - a, ba = b - a;
    float h = clamp( dot(pa, ba) / dot(ba , ba), 0.0, 1.0 );
    return length( pa - ba * h ) - r;
}

float motor(float _min, float _max, float time) {
    float t = 0.5 + 0.5 * sin(time);
    return mix(_min, _max, t);
}

float3 rotate_from_origin(float3 origin, float3 target, float r, float angle) {
    return float3(
                origin.x + r * cos(angle),
                origin.y + r * sin(angle),
                target.z
                );
}

float3 preserve(float3 p0, float3 p1, float len) {
    float3 v = p1 - p0;
    float3 u = normalize(v);
    return p0 + len * u;
}

float smin( float a, float b, float k ) {
    float h = clamp( 0.5+0.5*(b-a)/k, 0.0, 1.0 );
    return mix( b, a, h ) - k*h*(1.0-h);
}

float2 smin2( float2 a, float2 b, float k ) {
    float h = clamp( 0.5+0.5*(b.x-a.x)/k, 0.0, 1.0 );
    return mix( b, a, h ) - k*h*(1.0-h);
}

float2 map( float3 p) {
    float t = gtime * 2.0;
    float cx = 0.2;
    float cz = 0.1;
    float3 p0 = float3(-cx, 0.0, 0.0);
    float3 p1 = float3(-cx, -0.2, -cz);
    float3 p2 = float3(-cx, -0.4, -cz);
    float3 p3 = float3(-cx, 0.2, cz);
    float3 p4 = float3(-cx, -0.4, cz);

    float3 p5 = float3(cx, 0.0, 0.0);
    float3 p6 = float3(cx, -0.2, -cz);
    float3 p7 = float3(cx, -0.4, -cz);
    float3 p8 = float3(cx, 0.2, cz);
    float3 p9 = float3(cx, -0.4, cz);

    float3 p10 = float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    float3 p11 = float3(cx, -0.2, 0.0);

    float angle0 = 0.0;
    float angle1 = 0.0;
    p0.y = -motor(-0.05, 0.05, t * 4.0);
    angle0 = -motor(pi * 0.15, pi * 0.65, t * 2.0 - pi * 0.5);
    angle1 = -motor(pi * 0.15, pi * 0.65, t * 2.0 + pi * 0.5);
    p1 = rotate_from_origin(p0, p1, 0.2, pi-angle0);
    p3 = rotate_from_origin(p0, p3, 0.2, pi-angle1);
    angle0 += -motor(0.0, pi * 0.5, t * 2.0 + pi);
    angle1 += -motor(0.0, pi * 0.5, t * 2.0 + pi + pi);
    p2 = rotate_from_origin(p1, p2, 0.2, pi-angle0*0.6);
    p4 = rotate_from_origin(p3, p4, 0.2, pi-angle1*0.6);

    p5.y = -motor(-0.05, 0.05, t * 4.0);
    angle0 = -motor(pi * 0.15, pi * 0.65, t * 2.0 - pi * 0.5);
    angle1 = -motor(pi * 0.15, pi * 0.65, t * 2.0 + pi * 0.5);
    p6 = rotate_from_origin(p5, p6, 0.2, angle0);
    p8 = rotate_from_origin(p5, p8, 0.2, angle1);
    angle0 += -motor(0.0, pi * 0.5, t * 2.0 + pi);
    angle1 += -motor(0.0, pi * 0.5, t * 2.0 + pi + pi);
    p7 = rotate_from_origin(p6, p7, 0.2, angle0*0.6);
    p9 = rotate_from_origin(p8, p9, 0.2, angle1*0.6);

    p10.y = -motor(-0.02, 0.02, t * 4.0 - pi * 0.5);
    p11 = preserve(p5, p11, -0.25);
    float w = 0.05;

    float2 dd = float2(sdPlane(p - float3(0.0, -0.05, 0.0)), 1.0);

    float2 d = float2(10.0);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p0, p1, w), 30.0), 0.001);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p1, p2, w), 30.0), 0.001);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p0, p3, w), 40.0), 0.001);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p3, p4, w), 40.0), 0.001);

    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p5, p6, w), 30.0), 0.001);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p6, p7, w), 30.0), 0.001);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p5, p8, w), 40.0), 0.001);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p8, p9, w), 40.0), 0.001);

    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p0, p10, w + 0.0025 * sin(p.x * pi * 60.0)), 90.0), 0.1);
    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p10, p5, w), 90.0), 0.1 + 0.8*(0.5 + 0.5 * sin(gtime * 0.2)));

    d = smin2(d, float2(sdCapsule(p, p5, p11, w), 90.0), 0.15);

    d = smin2(d, dd, 0.01);
    return d;
}

float3 calcNormal( float3 p) {
    float2 e = float2(-1.0, 1.0) * 0.001;
    float3 nor = normalize(
                         e.xyy * map(p + e.xyy).x +
                         e.yxy * map(p + e.yxy).x +
                         e.yyx * map(p + e.yyx).x +
                         e.xxx * map(p + e.xxx).x
                         );
    return nor;
}

float2 castRay( float3 ro,  float3 rd,  float maxt) {
    float precis = 0.001;
    float h = precis * 2.0;
    float t = 0.0;
    float m = -1.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        if(abs(h) < precis || t > maxt) continue;
        float2 res = map(ro + rd * t);
        h = res.x;
        t += h;
        m = res.y;
    }
    if(t > maxt) m = -1.0;
    return float2(t, m);
}

float softshadow( float3 ro,  float3 rd,  float mint,  float maxt,  float k) {
    float sh = 1.0;
    float t = mint;
    float h = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if(t > maxt) continue;
        h = map(ro + rd * t).x;
        sh = min(sh, k * h / t);
        t += h;
    }
    return sh;
}

float3 render( float3 ro,  float3 rd) {
    float3 col = float3(1.0);
    float2 res = castRay(ro, rd, 20.0);
    float t = res.x;
    float m = res.y;

    col = 0.45 + 0.3*sin(float3(0.05,0.08,0.10)*(m-1.0)+gtime);
    if(abs(m - 1.0) < 0.01) col = float3(0.5);

    float3 pos = ro + rd * t;

    float3 nor = calcNormal(pos);
    float3 lig = normalize(float3(-0.4, 0.7, 0.5));
    float dif = clamp(dot(lig, nor), 0.0, 1.0);
    float spe = pow(clamp(dot(reflect(rd, nor), lig), 0.0, 1.0), 64.0);
    float fre = 1.0 - dot(-rd, nor);
    float sh = softshadow(pos, lig, 0.02, 20.0, 7.0);
    col = 1.0*col * (dif + spe + fre * 0.5) * (0.5 + sh * 0.5);

    return col;
}

kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    constant float &time [[buffer(1)]],
                    constant float &mouseX [[buffer(2)]],
                    constant float &mouseY [[buffer(3)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {

    int width = output.get_width();
    int height = output.get_height();
    float2 uv = float2(gid) / float2(width, height);
    float2 p = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;

    p.x *= width / height;

    float2 ms = 2.0 * float2(mouseX,mouseY) - 1.0;

    float3 ro = float3(ms.x * 2.0, 2.0 - ms.y, 1.5);
    float3 ta = float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    float3 cw = normalize(ta - ro);
    float3 cp = float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    float3 cu = normalize(cross(cw, cp));
    float3 cv = normalize(cross(cu, cw));
    float3 rd = normalize(p.x * cu + p.y * cv + 2.5 * cw);
    float3 col = render(ro, rd);

    output.write(float4(col, 1.), gid);
}
```

Comment: the screen coordinates are reversed in Metal as opposed to OpenGL.

Comment: What is the simplest way to invert the screen coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Marius's comment, I found out the solution. I just invert the `y` value by adding a `-` then everything become normal again:

```
float2 ms = 2.0 * normalize(float2(mouseX,-mouseY)) - 1.0;//<-- make mouseY negative
```